# Laravel Carbon: Why is now() exactly 1 day ahead?

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using this in a seeder:

```
'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
```

And am getting the correct date/time, but it is exactly 1 day ahead.

I have tried:

```
Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')),
```

In my seeder files, and it seems to work. However, when I am inserting records from a controller, the date is incorrect.

I am using `$table->timestamps();` to create the columns - is there a configuration setting that I can enter the correct time zone? Or, is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Laravel uses `'timezone' => 'UTC',` whereas your original timezone `America\Chicago` is `'timezone' => 'UTC-06:00'`.

If you want your timezone to be fixed to `America/Chicago` set your timezone to

```
'timezone' => 'America/Chicago'
```

in `config/app.php` file.

In case if you want to set it on run time you can accomplish that by following way:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying (and failing) to do this in the .env file